# Check whether the file exist and if not, show a message box

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a launcher that will launch the application and if not will gives a message box. I used `if..else`. However, even though the file exist the message box is still appearing. I'm not sure how to correct the code.

Here is my script code:

```
function LaunchAvaya {
    $testPath = Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\Avaya one-X Agent\OneXAgentUI.exe"
    $Checkavaya = Set-Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\Avaya one-X Agent"
    $startavaya = Start-Process "OneXAgentUI.exe"
}
```

Here is my `if..else`:

```
if (LaunchAvaya -eq $true) {
    LaunchAvaya
} else {
    $avmsgno = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('No Avaya is installed in this Workstation', 'Warning')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this to your code.  You need -PassThru (See `get-help Start-Process -full`).  Also your function is not returning a value.

Your `if` does not make sense because `if (LaunchAvaya -eq $true)` will launch the program, so the next line `LaunchAvaya` is supposed to do what?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null

function StartNotepad()
{
    $program = 'c:\windows\notepad.exe'
    $started = Start-Process $program -PassThru
    return ($started -ne $null)
}


if (StartNotepad)
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Notepad, yes")
}
else
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Notepad, no", 'Warning')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Test-Path` cmdlet to shorten what you're doing:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\Avaya one-X Agent\OneXAgentUI.exe'
if (Test-Path -Path $path)
{
    Start-Process -FilePath $path -WorkingDirectory (Split-Path -Path $path)
}
else
{
    $null = [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show('Avaya is not installed on this workstation', 'Warning')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- Your function doesn't return anything, because all output is captured. An empty return value evaluates to `$false` in a boolean comparison.
- The expression `LaunchAvaya -eq $true` will not compare the return value of the function with the value `$true`, but instead will invoke `LaunchAvaya` with the (undefined) parameter `-eq $true`. To be able to compare the return value of the function to a value either switch the operands:

  ```
  if ($true -eq LaunchAvaya) { ... }
  ```

  put the function call in parentheses:

  ```
  if ((LaunchAvaya) -eq $true) { ... }
  ```

  or remove operator and second operand entirely (PowerShell does a boolean evaluation by default):

  ```
  if (LaunchAvaya) { ... }
  ```

Change your code to something like this:

```
function LaunchAvaya {
    $avayaDir   = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Avaya\Avaya one-X Agent"
    $avayaAgent = "${avayaDir}\OneXAgentUI.exe"
    if (Test-Path $avayaAgent) {
        Start-Process -FilePath $avayaAgent -WorkingDirectory $avayaDir | Out-Null
        return $?
    }
}

if (LaunchAvaya) {
    'Avaya Agent started.'
} else {
    'Avaya Agent missing or not started.'
}
```

and the problem will disappear.